# Directory listing on ngnix

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Hi I am trying to list a set of pdfs using the directory listing feature on ngnix.

The files are located at /files

My dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM nginx
WORKDIR /files
COPY pdfs /files/

COPY conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 4200 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

default.conf has been modified

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /files {
        root /files;
        autoindex on;
    }
    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

but when I hit http://localhost/files, I get

404 Not Found
nginx/1.19.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a root `/some/path` under a `location /uri/prefix { ... }`, any file requested via `/uri/prefix/file` will be searched under the `/some/path/uri/prefix` directory. Check the difference between the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) nginx directives. You could either use an `alias /files;` directive or you can try to use `root "";` (I wonder if it would work but as for me it should).